# TLS vs HTTP Digest vs WS-Security

Tags: web-services, http, security, ssl, soap

For implementing SOAP web services, what are benefits and drawbacks of each of these security solutions

- TLS (Certificates)
- HTTP Digest Authentication
- WS-Security (SOAP digest authentication)

Would TLS certificates alone provide enough security for latter being more or less redundant, or should I also use HTTP digest or/and WS-Security? Especially, what benefits WS-Security gives over TLS/HTTP -level authentication and security?

Comment: TLS provides transport level security by securing your communication link. HTTP digest and WS-Security provides message level security by encrypting and signing your data. You need to use both together for best security. for example HTTPS ensure both level of security for your webservice, if you use certificates signed by proper internet authority.

Answer (score 3):

These are different technologies for different tasks:

- TLS:
  Secures the transport of the messages between client and server. Provides no authentication of client (unless client certificates are used).
- HTTP Digest authentication:
  Provides client authentication for the transport. Does not provide transport security.
- WS-Security: (from my understanding of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)):
  Integrates protection against sniffing and modification into the message itself, independent of the transport. Provides also client authentication by making the client sign the message.

If you are familiar with mail transport then WS-Security is similar to using PGP or S/MIME to encrypt the mails end-to-end and also sign the mails to prove who the sender is. TLS instead only secures the transport between the mail client and mail server or between mail servers, i.e. data in transit but not at rest. And authentication in mail transport only authenticates a specific hop and not end-to-end.